# Processing large documents using Word Javascript API / Office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, office-js, office-addins, javascript-api-for-office

For large Word documents its impossible to get all the text at once. For 100+ pager, doing so crashes the extension.

Is there a recommended or canonical approach to break down the document? One reasonable approach seems to be to process a document paragraph by paragraph:

```
Word.run(async context => {
    let paragraph = ????
    paragraph.load(['text'])
    await context.sync();
});
```

Where paragraph is the nth paragraph of the document.
Is there a way to access the nth paragraph of the document or load just the nth paragraph of a document?

Comment: Have you tried something like `context.document.body.paragraphs.items[n].load("text")`?

Comment: Ideally there is a way to call that without loading the entire array of items. context.document.body.paragraphs.items getting too big causes an add in to crash.